# looking for an idea for a .net web app with video chat

Tags: c#, .net, flash, video

I'm looking for an idea for a final project in .net.

I thought about building an IM AJAX app with .net but am kind of getting the feeling that the only way to do the video/audio chat is with flash and action script...

I have 4 month to do the project and the idea that in that time i will have the ability to learn a new language and implement the .net project with the flash part just for the video/audio doesn't seem very good.

Can any one correct me/give me any idea/help me/tell me if it is possible or should i look for a deferent project for that time frame?????

I really need some direction with that, I am looking for the past week at every answer over the wed and cant find a good solution.....please HELP!!!!!

10x.....What kind of server do i need if i want to use Silverlight (for the streaming, like red5 for flash and so on) and does visual studio 2008 support Silverlight?

Erez

Answer (score 0):

audio/video chat is only possible (under current technologies) via a plugin of some kind; flash is the more common one but Silverlight is good if you're already familiar w/ .net stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 4.0 was just announced with cam support.  From the demo it looked pretty easy.  You can download the beta.

Answer (score 0):

You really should check WebORB. If you install it, you'll get an example Flex Video Chat with source code (Flex and .NET). --> [Link](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/blog/2007/01/flex-video-chat-with-net-backend.html)

FluorineFX is also an alternative for .NET but I don't know if it comes with a Video Chat example.

Comment: FluorineFX has also support for Video Chat See http://www.fluorinefx.com/
I haven't got any experience with Red5. WebORB and FluorineFX are great to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Opentok-.NET-SDK](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-.NET-SDK)  as video stearming service and [signalr](http://signalr.net/) to map the users togetter